# Call functions from smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

could I interact with functions in my deployed contract without using truffle-contract?

I just want to run and play with my functions to check how they work.

I used MyContract.at("0x...").MyFunctionName(parameters,{from:"x0..."});

but it doesn't work.

Any idea or suggestions

Thanks

Comment: I am using version 3

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with truffle, how does your contract look like, and what functions are you calling with which parameters?

Comment: Add more info to your question

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you mean by "it's doesn't work", but I guess is that you are not seeing any output when running `MyContract.at("0x...").MyFunctionName(parameters,{from:"x0..."});` in the truffle console?

If yes, the reason is because invoking a method to an instance of a contract will give you a `Future`, and you must handle the result coming back from the call in an asynchronous way. For example, if the function return a value indicating that some computation has happened, you can print the returned value in the console by:

`MyContract.at("0x...").MyFunctionName(parameters,{from:"x0..."}).then(console.log)`

If you're writing unit tests (to be executed via `truffle test`), then you can handle the return value by doing this:

```
MyContract.at("0x...").MyFunctionName(parameters,{from:"x0..."}).then(function(returnedValue) { 
  // do something with the returnedValue, e.g.
  // assert.equal(returnedValue, 3, "The returned value must be 3");
});
```